# Are elements of the reproducing kernel Hilbert space of a Gaussian measure centered?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a locally convex space with $\mathcal{E}(X)$ being the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra.

Let $\gamma$ be a Gaussian measure on $X$. Bogachev defines the reproducing kernel Hilbert space $X_\gamma^\ast$ as the closure of the set
$$
\{f - a_\gamma(f) : f \in X^\ast\}, 
$$
in the $L^2(\gamma)$ norm. Above, $a_\gamma(f) := \int f \, d \gamma$.

At the bottom of page 44, he seems to indicate that it is possible for $g \in X_\gamma^\ast$ to have $a_\gamma(g) \neq 0$.

However, I am confused. Suppose $\epsilon > 0$, then there is $h \in X^\ast$ with such that $\|g - (h - a_\gamma(h))\|_{L^2(\gamma)} \leq \epsilon$.
This would seem to imply that
$$
|a_\gamma(g)| \leq \Big|\int g - (h - a_\mu(h)) d\gamma \Big| + \Big|\int h - a_\mu(h)  d\gamma \Big| \leq \|g - (h-a_\mu(h))\|_{L^2(\gamma)} \leq \epsilon?
$$
This would seem to indicate that $a_\gamma(g) = 0$.

What in my reasoning is wrong here?

Comment: It also seems to contradict the subsequent Lemma 2.2.8 in Bogachev's book (page 45) --- the name of this book is "Gaussian Measures."

Comment: By definition $g$ is in $X_\gamma^\ast$, so there is some $h_0 \in X^\ast$ such that $\|g - (h_0 - a_\gamma(h_0))\|_{L^2(\gamma)} \leq \epsilon$. However now I define $h = h_0 - a_\gamma(h_0)$. I do note I made the following error $h \not \in X^\ast$ unless already we had $a_\gamma(h_0)$. Instead I should have said $h \in L^2(\gamma)$. This is clear since $h_0 \in X^\ast \subset L^2(\gamma)$.

Comment: I made a minor modification to the argument to avoid this issue above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, I think the confusion is caused by you misunderstanding what Bogachev is saying so let me try restating it. The quick summary is that the claim is made for $f \in X^*$ rather than $f \in X_\gamma^*$.

At this stage in that book, you have maps $R_\gamma : X^* \to (X^*)'$ defined by $$R_\gamma(f)(g) = \int (f - a_\gamma(f)) (g - a_\gamma(g)) d\gamma$$ and  $\bar{R}_\gamma: X_\gamma^* \to (X^*)'$ (where I add the bar in comparison to Bogachev's notation for clarity) defined by $$\bar{R}_\gamma(f)(g) = \int f (g - a_\gamma(g)) d\gamma.$$

At the bottom of page 44, Bogachev is observing that if $f \in X^*$ then $f - a_\gamma(f) \in X_\gamma^*$ and
$$R_\gamma(f) = \bar{R}_\gamma(f - a_\gamma(f)).$$
However, if $a_\gamma(f) \neq 0$ then $f \not \in X_\gamma^*$ (by the argument you include in your question) so that $\bar{R}_\gamma(f)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: I see! He's essentially saying that on $X^\ast$, the difference is that $\overline R_{\gamma}$ already essentially assumes mean zero elements. (Now it makes sense why he is saying for centered $\gamma$ there is no difference!) Thanks!!!